# `string' undeclared

Tags: c++

Writing my first program, and my `using namespace std;` statement won't work. When I build the program I'm getting thrown this error:

```
C:\\Users\\p6735a\\Desktop\\Project\\game.cpp: In function `int main(int, char *)':
C:\\Users\\p6735a\\Desktop\\Project\\game.cpp:6: `string' undeclared (first use this         function)
C:\\Users\\p6735a\\Desktop\\Project\\game.cpp:6: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
C:\\Users\\p6735a\\Desktop\\Project\\game.cpp:6: for each function it appears in.)
C:\\Users\\p6735a\\Desktop\\Project\\game.cpp:6: parse error before `;'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input;
    int hp;

    cout << "You see a man. Would you like to kill him?\n1. Yes\n2. No" << endl;
    //cin >> input;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the string header:

```
#include <string>
```

But why have a `using namespace std` declaration at all? Simply use the objects individually:

```
using std::cout;
using std::string;
```

Comment: @amartin94, It's unspecified what headers other headers include, so you should always include what you need. I would be somewhat wary of a tutorial that doesn't do that. [Good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) won't.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
#include <string>
```

to your includes since `string` is from `<string>` header.

Meanwhile, it is bad practice to use `using namespace std` (see [Why using namespace std is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)), you'd better use:

```
std::string input
std::cout, std::endl
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio you need to have the new `#include "pch.h"`.